# Get Td cell from the last cell using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th class="center" style="width: 30%">Name</th>                 
                    <th class="hidden-480 center" style="width: 40%">URI</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone center" style="width: 30%">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                 
                <tr>
                    <td class="name">
                        Admin_Agency 
                    </td>       
                    <td class="uri">
                       /admin/agency
                    </td>
                    <td>                           
                        <a href="#modalEdit">
                            <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                            <span>Edit</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#modalDelete">
                            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                            <span>Delete</span>
                        </a>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="name">
                        System_Log 
                    </td>       
                    <td class="uri">
                        /admin/syslog
                    </td>
                    <td>                       
                        <a href="#modalEdit">
                            <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                            <span>Edit</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#modalDelete">
                            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                            <span>Delete</span>
                        </a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
           </tbody> 
     </table>
```

When click on Edit < a href="#modalEdit"> , I want to get the the data from the 2 sibling td , that is the  < td class="name"> , < td class="uri"> .
I add an onclick event on < a href="#modalEdit"> to parse data to the model when fire event click :

```
  var name = $(this).parent().siblings(".name").html()
  var uri = $(this).parent().siblings(".uri").html()
```

The code does not run.

Is there any suggestion for me?
THanks

Comment: What the %#!$ ? your code should work...! http://jsfiddle.net/g8nN5/

Comment: but it does not work :(

Comment: Your code works fine to me **[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ3EH/1/)**.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `closest()` to get its parent **tr** and then use `find()` to get td with via class selector, and the use `text()` to get the text between the opening and closing tag of td.

Like this:

```
var name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".name").text();
var uri = $(this).closest("tr").find(".uri").text();
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ3EH/)